# The order of characters of a text or number in excel via VBA coding

Tags: excel, vba

I recently works with excel. I need to copy some tables frome a Persian word file to excel. When I do this, the order of characters of texts and numbers changes. For example 1234 changes to 4321 and esfahani becomes inahafse. I need an vba program to reorder the text and numbers to the original order after pasting.
How can I write these codes?

Because I am beginner in excel, I changed the order of characters one by one. I need a program that help me to change the order automaticly.Also I would like to learning writing the vba codes by myself, and therefore need to guidance for beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will return a reversed string of text, based on an input:

```
Function reverse_string(text As String) As String
    reverse_string = StrReverse(text)
End Function
```

To use the function, you'll need to paste the above code into a new Module within your workbook.

Then, the function will be available to use within a cell, e.g. `=reverse_string(A1)`

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanke you very much. Is it possible to define a condition for negative numbers in this function? Because when using this function the mines sign moves to the right hand side of number.

Comment: Thanke you very much. Is it possible to define a condition for negative numbers in this function? Because when using this function the mines sign moves to the right hand side of number

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't be a problem to code. Though you'd be better off raising a new question.